# SQL Query returns duplicates when there is only one entry in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am experimenting with a test database to learn SQL, (MySQLi PHP)

I am pulling data from two tables add_images and item where the primary key for 'item' is referenced as the foreign key in 'add_images'. One 'item' will only has one image (add_images).

I need to get specific details about an item referenced by it's image_name.

I only have one entry in the database under d7.jpg which is of type VARCHAR. When I run the below query I get 34 results where I should only get one? why is this?

This also happens when I run the query in phpmyadmin

Here is the query

```
SELECT item_name, catagory, brand, store, location, month, year, details FROM add_images, item WHERE add_images.image_name='d7.jpg '
```

I think I am doing something fundamentallly wrong here in the way I have my tables configured?

Hope someone can advise!

Thanks

below are the two tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `add_images`( `image_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'unique id for an image',
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'unique id for the item been added',
  `image_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'name of the image',
  `type` enum('standard','deleted','profile','look','item') NOT NULL COMMENT 'status and       type of image',
  `date_added` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'date image was added',
  PRIMARY KEY (`image_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `item_id` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Add images to item or profile picture'     AUTO_INCREMENT=50 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item` (
 `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'primary key for item',
 `item_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'title name of the item',
 `catagory` enum('accessories','jackets','coats','footwear','legwear','jeanswear','dresses','shirts','tops','t-shirts','knitwear','skirts','shorts') NOT NULL COMMENT 'item catagory',
 `brand` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'brand of product',
 `store` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'store the item was purchased',
 `location` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'location the item was purchased',
 `month` enum('January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December') NOT NULL COMMENT 'month the item was purchased',
 `year` int(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'year the item was purchased',
 `details` varchar(500) NOT NULL COMMENT 'details about the item description',
 `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'date item created',
 PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `item_id` (`item_id`)
)    ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='holds data about the item'     AUTO_INCREMENT=72 ;
```

Comment: The ‘fundamentally’ wrong part is you are not specifying in your query how the two tables are related to each other. You are filtering only one of the tables but retrieving all the rows from the other.

Comment: +1000 for DDL. (Alas, only +1 is possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does a join but does not put any condition in the WHERE clause on the `item` table, so the query will combine *all* `item` entries with the add_images result no matter if the item_id matches. You'll want to change your query to reflect that;

```
SELECT item_name, catagory, brand, store, location, month, year, details 
FROM add_images, item 
WHERE add_images.image_name='d7.jpg '
  AND item.item_id = add_images.item_id;
```

EDIT: If you rewrite the query as an explicit join, it's easier to see if you're missing a link between the tables;

```
SELECT item_name, catagory, brand, store, location, month, year, details 
FROM add_images
JOIN item ON item.item_id = add_images.item_id   -- ON specifies the link
WHERE add_images.image_name='d7.jpg ';
```

Comment: oh I see, almost there! Thank you Joachim for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

it's because you are performing a JOIN (implictly using 2 tables in the FROM) without specifying the link between them.

The good syntax would be:

```
SELECT item_name, catagory, brand, store, location, month, year, details FROM add_images, item WHERE add_images.image_name='d7.jpg ' AND add_images.item_id=item.item_id
```

Comment: Also Thank you Dweeves for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You need a join condition:

```
SELECT item_name, catagory, brand, store, location, month, year, details 
FROM add_images, item 
WHERE add_images.item_id = item.item_id and add_images.image_name='d7.jpg '
```

- using SQL-89 syntax, or:

```
SELECT item_name, catagory, brand, store, location, month, year, details 
FROM add_images
JOIN item ON add_images.item_id = item.item_id 
WHERE add_images.image_name='d7.jpg '
```

- using SQL-92 syntax.

Comment: Also Thank you Mark for the explanation!